# Find the zeros of $f(x)=x^3−4x^2+x−4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring, cubics

I am to find the zeros and multiplicities of  $f(x)=x^3−4x^2+x−4$.

The solution provided in the answers section of my book is 4 with multiplicity 1. I arrived at $2\pm\sqrt(8)$.

My working:
$$x^3-4x^2+x-4$$
$$x(x^2-4x+1)-4$$

Then, focusing on the quadratic in the middle, I used [3BlueOneBrownVideo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHXO86wKeDY) (start from ~23 minutes) to find the zeros:

$$m = \frac{-b}{2}=\frac{4}{2}=2$$
$$d^2=m^2-p=2^2+4=8$$
$$r,s=m\pm\sqrt{d^2}$$
$$r,s=2\pm\sqrt{8}$$

The zeros I arrive at are therefore $2\pm\sqrt{8}$

How can I arrive at 4 per the solution? Granular baby steps much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to apply quadratic formula you must have $ax^2+bx+c=0$, if you have $x^3-4x^2+x-4=0$ then $x(x^2-4x+1)=4$ which doesn't tell you much,

Comment: You could arrive at $4$ by spotting the factor $x-4$ of the original cubic (this jumped out at me), or alternatively by using the rational root (here integer root) test and noting that any rational root has to be a factor of the constant term hence is $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4$. Since a cubic with integer coefficients always has at least one real root, you can expect an easy factor in a question like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following at least is right: $$x^3-4x^2+x-4=x^2(x-4)+1(x-4)=(x-4)(x^2+1),$$ which gives $$\{4,\pm i\}$$

Comment: Can you show me how you were able to arrive at $(x-4)(x^2+1)$?

Comment: @DougFir take $x^2$ common from first two terms

Comment: I'm unable to follow. I appreciate the answer but could you lay this out in granular steps? Though it may seem obvious to you it does not to me. If I start with $x^3-4x^2+x-4$ Then $x^2$ is not a factor because of the existence of x and -4?

Comment: @DougFir $x^3-4x^2 = x^2(x-4)$....

Comment: @Doug Fir, it's not a factor of the whole polynomial, just the first two terms.

Comment: Right, I see that. But I do not see how to bring it together and express it as $(x-4)(x^2+1)$. I can see that the first factor is just the remaining part of the original formula that was not factored. But I am unable to see the bigger picture on how to rewrite the whole expression i this way, which is why I was asking for granular baby steps

Comment: @Doug Fir  I added something. See now.

Comment: It's factor by grouping. I get it now. I did cover a section on that recently and should have noticed. Thank you very much, I was really stuck there!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) =x^3 - 4x^2 + x -4.$ 
Let $g(x) =x^3 - 4x^2 + x.$

Your initial approach was to find the zeroes of $g(x).$ 
This doesn't do you any good, because you are in effect identifying 
where $f(x)$ crosses the horizontal line $y = -4$, 
when what you want is to identify where $f(x)$ 
crosses the horizontal line $y = 0.$

Further, assuming that you have not studied the cubic equation,
as far as non-creative pedestrian methods are concerned,
in my opinion, you are **absolutely stuck**.

In my opinion, the **whole key** to the problem is to **notice** 
that the coefficients in $f(x)$ look like $1,-4,1,-4.$ 
This suggests that $(x-4)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, which 
turns out to be the case.

At this point, it is all downhill, assuming that you are comfortable
with quadratic equations.

**Addendum**

It occurs to me that an alternative **meta-cheating** method is to assume
that there is a rational root.  Although I am not familiar with such tests,
I suspect that such a test could be manually applied to discover the $(x-4)$
factor.

The idea behind my **meta-cheating** adjective is that it is reasonable to
presume that the *intent* of the questioner is that the problem would yield to what you had recently been taught in
class.  I doubt whether you have ventured into raw cubic equations.